# android Eclipse RecyclerView InflateException

Tags: android, eclipse, android-recyclerview

I am developing android project using Eclipse, integrating RecyclerView for my project. Currently I am using Recyclerview as a library project. But when I want to include its `android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar` I am getting InflateException at the runtime. I have tried all the possibilities to include jar into project but none of them are working, giving same error as InflateException.

Anyone has solved this problem with RecyclerView integration from Eclipse ?

Here is my logcat,

```
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): Process: com.example.recyclerviewtest, PID: 2324
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.recyclerviewtest/com.example.recyclerviewtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.example.recyclerviewtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     ... 10 more
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     ... 21 more
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/recyclerview/R$styleable;
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:481)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:450)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     ... 24 more
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.recyclerview.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.recyclerviewtest-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     ... 26 more
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.recyclerview.R$styleable
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):         ... 27 more
12-11 15:29:33.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Could you post some code how you creeate the recyclerview and its adapter?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.` have u import lib project properly?

Comment: Code works perfectly when I use recyclerview as a library project , but it fails when I include its jar into my project.

Comment: Add that jar file to your build path also.

Comment: Yes I did that too. Added jar file to build path also checked in Export tab.